# Determine two polynomials that are orthogonal to a inner product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, polynomials, inner-products, orthogonality

Im stuck in this exercise, where I have to determine two polynomials $p,q \neq 0$ that are orthogonal in regards to the inner product, where $i^2=-1$:

$$
\langle p,q \rangle = p(i) \cdot \overline{q(i)} + p(1) \cdot q(1) + \overline{p(i)} \cdot q(i)
$$

$p,q \in P_3\mathbb{(R)}$ and have degree $\leq2$

$p(\alpha)=c_0+c_1\alpha+c_2\alpha^2$

$q(\beta)=d_0+d_1\beta+d_2\beta^2$

I know that the definition of orthogonality is

$\langle p,q \rangle=0$

I don't know how to solve this exercise. 
Do I have to solve the inner product equal to zero and isolate for $p$ and then $q$?

Or do I have to do something else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: One long, but purely computational method would be to nominate two linearly independent polynomials, e.g. $1$ and $x$, then apply Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: okay thanks, i will try that :)

Comment: There is no need to use Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation. Just let $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $q=1$. Then solve for $\langle p,q\rangle=0$ directly.